# A phrase or expression for: Work on task 2 is dependant on task 1 finishing

Tags: phrases, idiom-requests, phrase-requests

Task 1 should be finished in order to start working on task 2. 
Task 2 is not done yet.

I want to convey we haven't even finished task 1 so task 2 is indefinitely delayed.

I do not exactly know but I think there is a phrase for that.

Can anybody put this in a format similar to -

> Forget about task 2 even task 1 is not finished

Comment: Don't put the cart before the horse.

Comment: Task 1 is a prerequisite ("prereq") for starting/completing task 2.

Comment: If your'e doing software development (or any business process influenced by it), it's common to say that "task 1 is a blocker for task 2".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about **conditioned**, derived from *condition*? From Cambridge:

> *[condition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/condition)*: an arrangement that must exist before something else can happen

Your example:

> *The completion of task 2 is **conditioned** on the completion of task 1.*

A related possibility is the mathematical term **necessary condition**.

Your example:

> *The completion of task 1 is a **necessary condition** for the completion of task 2.*

That is, task 2 cannot be completed unless and until the **necessary condition** -- the completion of task 1 -- has been met first.

Answer (score 2):

Task 2 is contingent on the completion of task 1.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! Please try to elaborate on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Starting task2 is dependent upon finishing task1. Or One of the requirements to starting task2 is the completion of task1.

Answer (score -1):

Task 1 must be finished before commencement of task 2.